# Email Verification using php and mysql : SMTP connect() failed for webmail

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, webmail

This is my php code for sending email verification link to user account

```
<?php
// php mailer code starts
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";               
    $mail->Host = "smtp.domain.in";     
    $mail->Port = 25;                   

    $mail->Username = 'admin@domain.in';
    $mail->Password = 'password';

    $mail->SetFrom('admin@domain.in', 'Admin');
    $mail->AddAddress($email);

    $mail->Subject = trim("Email Verifcation");
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    try {
      $mail->send();
      $msg = "An email has been sent for verfication.";
      $msgType = "success";
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      $msg = $ex->getMessage();
      $msgType = "warning";
    }

?>
```

This code is working for gmail account like `xyz@gmail.com`. But its not working If I use webamail account like `admin@domain.in`.

I get `'SMTP connect() failed'` error.

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Ask `domain.in` about correct smtp settings. E.g. the port could be something different from 25.

Comment: 25 is usually the local port

Answer (score 0):

As always, the first thing you should do is [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#using-encryption). You should be able to figure out from this section that this will not work:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 25;
```

That's asking for implicit TLS to work on a port that doesn't typically support it, so it will fail to connect. Do *one* of these instead:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

or

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Other combinations are unlikely to work. You may have other issues too, but that one is fatal.